# How do I create a single slicer from a group of columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data loaded into Power Bi that look like this:

| ID | TYPE | Product 1 | Product 2 | Product 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | B | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | A | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 0 | 0 |

So every column besides the "ID" and "TYPE" columns, is a binary 0/1 column, that indicates whether certain person acquire given product.

What I want to do, is to create a single dropdown slicer with Product 1, Product 2 and Product 3 values, that will filter only certain persons which acquire selected Product.

Comment: What did you try so far and what is not working? One way to do it is to transform your current table to a so-called long table (or “to unpivot it”): i.e. instead of separate columns for each product you have one column “Product” where Product1..3 are values. e.g. you will have 2 rows here: ID 1, Type A, Product Product1 and ID 1, Type A, Product Product2. On top of my head you could also use SWITCH to solve it. Maybe you get lucky, and there are others here to give your the “free code service”. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, i tried the trick with creating another table with one product column, but unfortunaltely in my main table i do not have a unique key column since ID is not unique, so i cannot make a relationship between tables.

Comment: You can check this answer I give last week to another question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364246/power-bi-field-parameter-filtering/76369801#76369801

Comment: After creating/transforming to the long table, what are the requirements that you would still need the original wide table for? I just had a look at the solution from mkRabbani. Yes, it’s roughly what I also had in mind regarding SWITCH. Moreover, there is also a proposal from Luke_0 to that question from last week, which suggests a long table as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cant get a table with one product column before you connect to Power-BI and everything else fails you can to the following:

In the query editor create a new query and refer it to your table above

`= YourTableName`

So you get the table 3 times. Now for table one delete the columns 4 & 5, for table two delete columns 3 & 5 and for table three delete column 3 & 4. Then rename all columns identical `ID, Type, Product`.

In the last step you under `Home > Append Queries` you can append all three tables. Now you got your final table with just one `Product` column.

Comment: Sorry, in between might need to add/transform the 1/0 from each of those columns to the respective header names as well, no? Also there is a built-in: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098 (with optional, additional steps to get rid of the rows with 0s and then the complete value column with the 1s, so just to keep the attribute column)

Comment: Well I guess the 0/1 are just sample data. A product column normally has some other information in it. But actually you dont need to transform the header names with the solution above.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. What I meant is, if you have look on the picture from the [built-in unpivot function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098): the appending of the 3 columns’ rows will produce the blue-colored [Values] but misses the green [Attributes]. For this use case, the indication of the Product 1..3 is lost/missing. Unless transforming the “1” to the respective Product1..3 before appending.

Comment: Ah ok I know what you mean. But @Grzegorz Szymala doesn´t need this information in his case. At least thats how I did understand his question because in the comment he already tried to combine this 3 columns to 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your fact table being structured correctly. (What happens if you add "Product 4"? 5?)
If you want to see who bought Product A and Product B, you can use INTERSECT(PeopleWhoBoughtA, PeopleWhoBoughtB)

So what kind of analysis are you attempting with this?