# Power BI Desktop - Create a slicer with Unique values applied to multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, slice, slicers

I have a table with hundreds of tasks. Those tasks can be have multiple assignees, so I have multiple columns for capturing them: Assignee.1, Assignee.2, and so on. I want to create a single slice where it filters tasks based on the name of the assignee, regardless if this comes up in the Column 1, 2, 3... - any column which assignees are captured.

Sample of the data structure:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is not working out? I would also recommend to use the search function. Actually, I think this question can be closed. You may have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76388533/how-do-i-create-a-single-slicer-from-a-group-of-columns Cheers! P.S. You may also want to have look at the section below about **Related questions** ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This data format is not suitable for what you want to do. You need to have a table with two columns - `Task Title` and `Assignee`. If you can't get your data in a proper format, you can transform this one. [Duplicate](https://radacad.com/reference-vs-duplicate-in-power-bi-power-query-back-to-basics) your table (let's rename the copy to `Task Users` for example), select the assignee columns and [unpivot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column) them (click `Transform` -> `Unpivot Columns`). Delete the `Attribute` column (you don't need it) and rename `Value` to `User Name`. Remove the rows with blank values in `User Name` column by clicking the button in the header and unselecting the `(blank)` value.

At the end you should end with something like this:

[image]

Now you should have a relationship between `Tasks` -> `Title` and `Task Users` -> `Title` (add it manually if Power BI doesn't detect this automatically). Make sure that the [cross filter direction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-bidirectional-filtering) of this relationship is set to `Both`:

[image]

Now you can add `Task Users` -> `User Name` column to a slicer in your report and it will filter the Tasks table properly:

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrey. This is absolutely fantastic. Thank you very much. Implemented and worked beautifully!!

Comment: @MarceloBastos Thank you! It will be nice to accept and upvote the helpful answers.