# What is the optimal approach to separate and transform multiple country codes into a dimension table in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, data-modeling

I am working on a project in power bi when I making the data modeling, one of the columns has multiple values about country code, I want to separate them and then transform them into a dimension table.

[enter image description here]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7MkL.png]

but when I merge it with the origin table which considered to be a fact, I have a problem of increasing the size of the fact table as an example from 10000 rows to 84000 rows, also it causes many to many relationship if I add an index for the fact table, is this way will be right?
can you suggest any other way much optimized and memory size saving?
I attached a screenshot for the main column and screenshots for the two dimension tables I created from it.

[enter image description here]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NN62H.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ3VO.png]

Comment: You are on the right track. You'll want three tables: fact <-> countryx/country  <- country. Where countryx/country is an explosion of {{"AB,CD","AB"},{"AB,CD","CD"}}.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Power BI Field Parameter Filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76364246/power-bi-field-parameter-filtering)

Comment: @Luke_0 Can you explain more, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to map each `[codCountry]` to the respective individual `[Country-Code]`. This is best performed in PowerQuery because we will be parsing strings.

1. Create a new table referencing the fact table.

[image]

2. Group the table by `[CodCountry]`. This will remove all columns but `[CodCountry]`, and will remove all duplicate values in that column. Generally the group-by function is better than the distinct function because it will [query fold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding) in more data sources. Remove the required aggregation string in step editor.

[image]

2. Create a column using the `Text.Split()` function.

`Text.Split( [codCountry], "," )`.

3. Expand the column to new rows.

[image]

4. Reference this new table to make a new table (like in step 1). This will be your country dimension table if you don't already have one. If you do, skip this step. After creating the new table, just remove all columns but country-code and remove duplicates from it.
5. Load these changes to your model and create relationships between the tables. The relationship between the fact table and the country code mapping table should be many-to-many (bi-directional).

[image]

This will allow you to filter your fact table by country code while keeping your mapping table as minimal as possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation.
the question here can we refer to the fact table with(Many to one) relationship, I mean can the side of the fact be as one?

Comment: You are right, my bad. Just oversimplified my example dataset a little too far. Should be many-to-many

Comment: It's ok, thanks for your help. Will it be right if it's many to many?

Comment: Yep! It just means that different country selections can/will return the same facts (e.g., ID or MY will both return fact #27928). If this solved your question, be sure to mark as the accepted answer. Thank you!